# file_get_contents not working in Yii widget's view

Tags: php, yii

I have Yii 1.1 and a widget with view, where I call `file_get_contents` php function for external address (https from https). I call `https://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/...` - they provide coordinates by IP address. It fails with 503 error:

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Service
>   Temporarily Unavailable

But it works perfectly on static view page.
It also works everywhere on my developer machine.
I have `allow_url_fopen = On` in my php.ini on server.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Not enough information here to solve it. My hunch is that you need to set a user agent string, which is empty by default for `file_get_contents`. I've seen a lot of API's reject requests for that reason. However, 503 is the wrong response code to send, so the API provider doesn't seem compliant for that scenario. However, this is likely considering they also invalidly send a 200 for an Invalid API key error - which should be 401

Comment: OK, I've just set user agent string in header options with `stream_context_create`, but nothing changed. As I said, everything works great when I call that API from static php page. The headers the same as I do it from widget's view. What kind of information you need? Also, you can create your own api key here: http://ipinfodb.com/register.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this solve it (I'm not sure if your URL is using special characters...)?

```
file_get_contents(urlencode('https://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/...'));
```

Or, if you have curl enabled, you could use something like this:

```
function getData($url){

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 3);     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
    }
```

Comment: Checked cURL one more time, it's ok, works fine as I set timeout for request, thank you. Anyway, this could not be correct answer for the question.

Comment: Hi, youw welcome. Still thinking about a different solution, but (in all fairness) it did solve your problem though ;)

Comment: Thanks :) ! I'll keep thinking about it though and if i come up with something else, ill post it in this comment :).

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaking (and i'm tired while going over the manual ...) but would json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/...')); do the trick as well? Don't hold this against me if i'm absolutely wrong, again, really tired...